# Error on start test: NUnit.AssemblyHooks: Method not found: Void Techtalk.Specflow.Tracing: Allure.SpecflowPlugin.AllurePlugin

Tags: c#, specflow, allure

I am migration my project from .Net 4.7.1 to Core 3.1.
Update and use dll`s:

- SpecFlow        (3.6.23)
- SpecFlow.Allure (3.5.0.4)
- SpecFlow.NUint  (3.6.23)
- SpecFlow.NUnit.Runners (3.6.23)
- SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation (3.6.23)
- Allure.Commons (3.5.0.4)
- Allure.SpecFlowPlugin(3.5.0.4)
- NUnit.Allure (1.0.11)
- NUnit (3.12.0)

On start test I get error in NUnit.AssemblyHooks.cs,`TestRunnerManager.OnTestRunStart(currentAssembly)`:

```
 OneTimeSetUp: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void TechTalk.SpecFlow.Tracing.ITestTracer.TraceError(System.Exception)'.
```

In Debug out exist field:
`Source=Allure.SpecFlowPlugin`

Please, help to solve problem with exception.

Answer (score 0):

With SpecFlow 3.6 we made a breaking change in this API and as we released it only some hours ago, Allure didn't yet adjust their plugin to this change.

Use SpecFlow 3.5 until the Allure plugin is supporting SpecFlow 3.6.

Comment: Thank you! 
I not sure this right, but I face next question. 
(Specflow 3.5.5/3.5.14)

On step "Scenario" in .feature I face to: "Value cannot be null.(Parameter key)" 
Using russians lang in .feature.
With .Net 4.7.1 all work correct.

Answer (score 0):

At there moment the Allure.SpecFlowPlugin does not support versions of SpecFlow above version 3.6.

There is an active pull request to bump all packages and support the latest SpecFlow.

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/pull/232